# Duda componente Goodby/csv del Packagist

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber si alguien ha usado el componente mencionado en el título (Goodby/csv) para PHP, debido a que tengo un problema con el mismo. Les explico, estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que gestiona licencias de software donde los usuarios se cargan mediante ficheros csv a una BD MySQL y para ello quiero contemplar que cada vez que subo un fichero con los alumnos, se compruebe cada registro (fila del csv) para ver si existe en la BD y no duplicarlo. El problema es que el componente parece ser que hace un bucle impícito de toso las sentencias que están delimitadas (csv) y en ese intervalo no puedo comprobar cada fila para dicho propósito. Les paso el código a ver si podéis verlo con claridad.

Esta es una de la funciones que se encargan de lo comentado:

```
public function InsertarProfesores($ficheroTmp){
        try{
            $config = new LexerConfig();
            $config
                ->setDelimiter(";") // Customize delimiter. Default value is comma(,)
                ->setEnclosure("'")  // Customize enclosure. Default value is double quotation(")
                ->setEscape("\\")    // Customize escape character. Default value is backslash(\)
                ->setToCharset('UTF-8') // Customize target encoding. Default value is null, no converting.

            ;
            $lexer = new Lexer($config);
            $interpreter = new Interpreter();
            $pdo = $this->pdo;
            $interpreter->addObserver(function(array $columns) use ($pdo) {

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO profesores (departamento,dni,nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido,tlf_sms,direccion,email,num_afiliacion, tutor_de) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                $stmt->execute($columns);
            });

            $lexer->parse($ficheroTmp, $interpreter);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas!

No he usado el **Goodby/csv**, pero por lo que veo en el código, hace un bucle para "preparar" la consulta con los registros, has probado incluir ahí un `SELECT`  ? Aun que no se muy bien como recuperarías el valor del DNI.

Mi consejo es utilizar las funciones nativas de PHP.

```
public function InsertarProfesores($ficheroTmp){
    try{
        $config = new LexerConfig();
        $config
            ->setDelimiter(";") // Customize delimiter. Default value is comma(,)
            ->setEnclosure("'")  // Customize enclosure. Default value is double quotation(")
            ->setEscape("\\")    // Customize escape character. Default value is backslash(\)
            ->setToCharset('UTF-8') // Customize target encoding. Default value is null, no converting.

        ;
        $lexer = new Lexer($config);
        $interpreter = new Interpreter();
        $pdo = $this->pdo;
        $interpreter->addObserver(function(array $columns) use ($pdo) {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT dni FROM profesores WHERE departamento = ? AND dni = ?');
            $stmt->execute($columns);
            $cuenta = $stmt->rowCount();
            echo $cuenta ;
            if($cuenta){
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO profesores (departamento,dni,nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido,tlf_sms,direccion,email,num_afiliacion, tutor_de) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                $stmt->execute($columns);
            }
        });

        $lexer->parse($ficheroTmp, $interpreter);

    }catch(Exception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```